# WSDL Document Literal with parts referencing XSD types

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I've been reading [WSDL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) specification and there's one thing that seems strange to me - what (beside WS-I Basic Profile) prevents me from doing this:

```
<message name="helloRequest">
    <part name="arg1" type="xs:string" />
</message>
<message name="helloResponse">
    <part name="result" type="xs:string" />
</message>

<portType name="Port02">
    <operation name="hello">
        <input message="tns:helloRequest" name="helloRequest" />
        <output message="tns:helloResponse" name="helloResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="Port02SoapBinding" type="tns:Port02">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="hello">
        <input name="helloRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </input>
        <output name="helloResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

It's document/literal web service, but in/out messages contain parts which refer to XSD (simple) types, not global elements.

The WSDL fragment is not that scary - Both Axis1 and CXF generate soap body elements which have names derived from part names, but [WSDL 1.1, 3.5: soap:body](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap%3abody) says:

> If use is literal, then each part references a concrete schema definition using either the element or type attribute. In the first case, [...]. In the second, the type referenced by the part becomes the schema type of the enclosing element (**Body for document style** or part accessor element for rpc style).

Does that mean that the resulting SOAP message (according to WSDL specification) will look like this (text content inside SOAP body)?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xsi:type="xs:string">value</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's edge case - in practice all java (axis1, axis2, cxf, jaxrpc-ri) implementations I've checked wrap String (or any simple) type with element named after part's name with no namespace.

Axis1:

```
private static void _initOperationDesc1(){
    org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc oper;
    org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc param;
    oper = new org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc();
    oper.setName("hello");
    param = new org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "arg1"), org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc.IN, new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"), java.lang.String.class, false, false);
    oper.addParameter(param);
    oper.setReturnType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
    oper.setReturnClass(java.lang.String.class);
    oper.setReturnQName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "result"));
    oper.setStyle(org.apache.axis.constants.Style.DOCUMENT);
    oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.constants.Use.LITERAL);
    _operations[0] = oper;
}
```

JAXRPC-RI:

```
SOAPBlockInfo _bodyBlock = new SOAPBlockInfo(ns1_hello_arg1_QNAME);
_bodyBlock.setValue(arg1);
_bodyBlock.setSerializer(ns2_myns2_string__java_lang_String_String_Serializer);
_request.setBody(_bodyBlock);
...
private static final javax.xml.namespace.QName ns1_hello_arg1_QNAME = new QName("", "arg1");
```

So you should get:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <arg1>value</arg1>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

EDIT: Also in WSDL 2.0 there are no *messages* and operation inputs and outputs must refer to elements (or #any or #none or #other).